# handle multiple webview instance in android

Tags: android

I want to load two html pages into two different webviews in android.The first html only going to display. The second html should act as background. The script used in second html page need to run, but it won't display to the user. Let me know this is possible in android..

Thanks

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have tried at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes dude it is possible

Add a `WebView` and set it visibility to `View.GONE`

Like

```
    WebView webView2=new WebView(this);
    webView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then

```
       webView2.loadUrl("javascript:MyJSFunction(..)
```

Comment: its working..Thank u. this is my working code..                                webView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
               view.loadUrl("javascript:showAlert();");
            }
        });